# how to fix MAP reference?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,

I have one question about the reference of the Map created by Rtabmap. The problem is that when I am in localization mode, and I want to specify a fixed goal for the vehicle, each time the coordinate of this goal is different.
I mean every time that I launch rtabmap, I have to extract the coordinate of that goal, so it seems that the reference of the map is not fixed and every time changes.

How can I fix this issue?
thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380526/how-to-fix-map-reference?!/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure `RGBD/OptimizeFromGraphEnd` is false (default is false). Otherwise, the map will be in odom frame (which would change every time the robot is restarted). Until the robot is localized in the map, the pose in the map would not be reliable, unless the robot is restarting exactly from where it shut down.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2021-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0